# How To parse UITextField value from one Nib to another

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

How can I parse UITextField value from one Nib file to another, By initWithNibName

Here is the Code for the First View

```
-(IBAction)testbuttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    //test.text=@"hello H R U";
    detailsViewController=[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    detailsViewController.address1=txtName;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:detailsViewController.view];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

- txtName is UITextField here.
- and In the FlipsideViewController address1 is UITextField
- and in the FlipsideViewController.m I am trying to fetch it by address1.text.

Now when I am running the app. First View Appear with the UITextField to which txtName is attached. On Button Click new View appeared by It is not Printing address1.text value which I have inputed in the previous view

Comment: You want to pass the value of the text somebody entered or the actual instance of the control? Either way, you wouldn't really pass this during the init call but rather through a property or directly to the new control after the nib was loaded.

Comment: Can you Provide me with the sample code
Because what I am doing is detailsViewController=[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
 detailsViewController.address1=txtName;

and Calling address1.text in FlipsideViewController. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong

Comment: Edit your question and post the code so we can help. Otherwise it is too difficult.